# How to produce messages with headers in Kafka 0.11 using console producer?

Tags: apache-kafka

How to produce messages with headers in Kafka 0.11 using console producer?

I didn't find any description in Kafka document about this.

Answer (score 9):

**Update**: Since Kafka 3.2, you can produce records with headers using the `kafka-console-producer.sh` tool. For details, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-798%3A+Add+possibility+to+write+kafka+headers+in+Kafka+Console+Producer

---

Using the `kafka-console-producer.sh` tool (`ConsoleProducer.scala`) you cannot produce messages with headers.

You need to write your own small application. `Headers` are passed in when creating a `ProducerRecord`. For example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties producerConfig = new Properties();
    producerConfig.load(new FileInputStream("producer.properties"));

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerConfig);

    List<Header> headers = Arrays.asList(new RecordHeader("header_key", "header_value".getBytes()));
    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic", 0, "key", "value", headers);
    Future<RecordMetadata> future = producer.send(record);
    future.get();

    producer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `kcat` to produce message with header.

```
kcat -P -b localhost:9092 -H "facilityCountryCode=US" -H "facilityNum=32619" \
-t test.topic.to.mq testkafkaproducerfile.json
```

for more information check github page: https://github.com/edenhill/kcat