# Is there a way to add headers in kafka-console-producer.sh

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'd like to use the kafka-console-producer.sh to fire a few JSON messages with Kafka headers.

Is this possible?

```
docker exec -it kafka_1 /opt/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic my-topic --producer.config /opt/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/config/my-custom.properties
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to produce messages with headers in Kafka 0.11 using console producer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217828/how-to-produce-messages-with-headers-in-kafka-0-11-using-console-producer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, but you can with `kafkacat`'s `-H` argument:

Produce:

```
echo '{"col_foo":1}'|kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t test -P -H foo=bar
```

Consume:

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t test -C -f '-----\nTopic %t[%p]\nOffset: %o\nHeaders: %h\nKey: %k\nPayload (%S bytes): %s\n'
-----
Topic test[0]
Offset: 0
Headers: foo=bar
Key:
Payload (9 bytes): col_foo:1
% Reached end of topic test [0] at offset 1
```

Comment: Now it's called `kcat`, just for the record :)

Answer (score 6):

Starting from kafka 3.1.0, there is an option to turn on headers parsing `parse.headers=true` and then you just place them before your record value. Info from [docs](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#L222):

```
| parse.headers=true:
|  "h1:v1,h2:v2...\tvalue"
```

So your command will look like this:

`kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic_name --property parse.headers=true`

and then you should pass:

`header_name:header_value\trecord_value`

Comment: for what it's worth. The default property for `headers.delimiter` is `\t`. After some confusion. This command will need --property headers.delimiter='\n' passed along as well otherwise the CLI complains with exceptions regarding the header delimiter.

Comment: I am getting No headers delimiter found on line number 1: with this message "key:value\t sa"

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-798%3A+Add+possibility+to+write+kafka+headers+in+Kafka+Console+Producer

Comment: Can you add one example with header as json payload and value as json payload as well.

Comment: I had to add `--property headers.delimiter=\t`. Wasn't defined as default on my system 

Answer (score 0):

Consumer producer command:

```
docker exec -it container_id kafka-console-producer.sh --topic my-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property parse.headers=true --property headers.key.separator=: --property headers.delimiter=\t
```

Payload format:

```
header_name:header_value t payload_value
```

Console consumer command:

```
docker exec -it container_id kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic my-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property print.headers=true
```